# Para que serve e como usar o "display: contents" do CSS?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, css-display

Recentemente vi que existe um novo tipo de `display` no CSS o `display: contents`, mas não entendi direito a intenção de uso dele? https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/display

Ele parece ser apenas para remover o CSS do *container*... Mas é só para isso que ele serve mesmo? ***É para remover o CSS do pai?***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Dúvidas**

- Afinal qual é a indicação de uso para esse `display`?
- E se existe alguma contra indicação qual seria?

Código do exemplo:

```css
.content {
  border: 2px solid #999;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 400px;
/*   display: contents; */
}

.inner {
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="inner">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta eligendi quia accusantium, placeat, blanditiis consequuntur voluptatum iusto amet voluptate cupiditate architecto porro sapiente, illum eaque commodi tempore facilis? Sunt, corrupti?</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Eu achei esse artigo, bem interessante por sinal, que pode servir de alguma base argumentativa para as perguntas que você fez > https://medium.com/@oieduardorabelo/css-como-display-contents-funciona-1290a705df98

Comment: É por ai mesmo @AndreiCoelho o assunto é um pouco complexo. Por isso resolvi deixar a pergunta ai no ar....

Comment: `display: contents` torna o elemento um contêiner semelhante a uma "película" extremamente fina, flexível e invisível. Ideal para contêineres que não possuem nenhuma estilização relacionada e servem apenas para agrupar outros elementos

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Na verdade ele não elimina o CSS do container, ele elimina o próprio container
>   do layout, deixando apenas os elementos filhos.

A função da propriedade é alterar visualmente um ou mais elementos mantendo a semântica do HTML, geralmente quando a marcação (tag) do elemento-pai não interessa naquele contexto, fazendo com que os elementos filhos se tornem filhos diretos do avô (apenas visualmente):

```
<div> ← Avô
   <div> ← Pai
      <div></div> ← Neto
   </div>
</div>
```

Ao adicionar a propriedade na *div-pai*, o a *div-neto* se torna visualmente uma "*div-pai*" (filha direta da *div-avô*), mas repito, apenas visualmente no layout. No DOM, a *div-pai* continua sendo a *div-pai*. Seria como se você tivesse comentado a tag (SERIA, mas a tag continua ativa no DOM):

```
<div> ← Avô
   <!-- <div style="display: contents"> ← Pai -->
      <div></div> ← Neto
   <!-- </div> -->
</div>
```

A indicação de uso vai depender muito do layout que se deseja construir e da semântica que se deseja manter.

Um exemplo hipotético seria: eu quero construir um menu horizontal sendo que os dois primeiros links sejam duas `<li>`, mas, por questões de semântica, essas `li`'s devem estar dentro de uma tag `<ul>`. O `display: contents` torna isso possível "eliminando" a tag `ul` (apenas visualmente) fazendo com que as `li`'s se comportem como parte do grid do menu assim como os outros links `<a>`, mas a estrutura da lista fica intacta no DOM:

```css
.content{
   display: flex;
   background-color: black;
}

.content > *, .content ul li, .content ul li a{
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   flex: 1;
}

.content > *{
   height: 50px;
   background-color: lightgreen;
   margin: 2px;
}

.content ul li{
   background-color: yellow;
   margin: 2px;
}

.content ul li a{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}

.content ul{ display: contents; }
```

```html
<div class="content">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
   </ul>
   <a href="#">Link 3</a>
   <a href="#">Link 4</a>
</div>
```

Doutra sorte isso não seria possível, ou seja, não seria possível utilizar uma lista `<ul>` para esse propósito. Veja como ficaria o menu sem o `display: contents` na `ul`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja que as `li`'s não conseguem se integrar ao grid do menu por serem filhas do elemento `ul`, que por sua vez é filho do elemento `.content`. O `display: contents` torna, **apenas visualmente** na tela, as `li`'s filhas diretas do `.content`, tornando-as parte do grid do menu juntamente com os outros dois elementos `<a>`.

Um artigo de referência que aborda o assunto de forma bem objetiva (em inglês):

- https://codeburst.io/display-contents-8c9226bd4602

Comment: Esse exemplo de uso é realmente muito bom!

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo esclarecimento ;)

Comment: Valeu HugoCSS! Depois de estudar bastante a propriedade eu entendi pra que ela funciona. Fods é saber explicar com clareza cristalina, mas me esforcei. Difícil é usar ela em algum momento, mas vai que aparece uma oportunidade :D

Answer (score -2):

Um caso de uso muito interessante que pode ser aplicado com o `Vue.js` é quando você está construindo um checklist de ítens e você quer que o conteúdo do `li` seja um `slot` (para que o conteúdo seja customizável) e você quer que esse conteúdo seja clicável para que assim ative/desative o checkbox do `li` correspondente. Sendo assim, o seu componente ficaria parecido com algo assim:

```html
<ul>
  <li v-for="item in listItems" :key="item.id">
    <div class="item">
      <input type="checkbox" @change="toggleSelection(item)" />
      <div class="wrapper" @click="toggleSelection(item)">
        <slot :item="item"></slot>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Se você não criar um css definindo que a div wrapper seja `display: contents`, o conteúdo que será renderizado no slot poderá ter seu layout quebrado por conta da classe wrapper ser uma div, a qual possui diversos atributos pré estabelecidos pelos browsers. Ao definir `display: contents` para a div wrapper o css dela será "ignorado" fazendo com que e conteúdo do `li` seja renderizado como se ele fosse um filho direto da `div.item`. Dessa forma nós conseguimos usar a `div.wrapper` apenas como uma forma de definir um evento de click para o seu conteúdo.