# Existe alguma forma de "desmembrar" um elemento filho de um elemento pai?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Eu tenho a seguinte situação na versão destkop de um template:

```
<div class="bloco-pai">
    ...
    <div class="bloco-filho">
</div>
```

Quando o template fosse visualizado no mobile gostaria que a estrutura se desdobrasse como:

```
<div class="bloco-pai">
   ...
</div>
<div class="bloco-filho">
   ...
</div>
```

Existe alguma classe de Bootstrap que faça isso?

Comment: Se precisa fazer isso, talvez seja mais interessante rever a estrutura do seu HTML. Idealmente a semântica do HTML não deveria mudar entre desktop e mobile, a outline se mantém a mesma. Se for só uma questão estética, você não precisa "desfiliar", apenas estilizar com o CSS, mas para isso será necessário que você descreva como gostaria de exibir tais elementos e preferencialmente elabore um [mcve].

Comment: "desmembrar" não sei se é possível. Mas creio que via *CSS* você pode deixar seu layout responsivo e assim conseguir esconder algo no desktop ou esconder algo no mobile e vice versa.

Comment: Se vc realmente quer fazer isso, talvez essa quastão possa te interessar https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/352318/para-que-serve-e-como-usar-o-display-contents-do-css mas o mais provável é que vc na realidade não precise fazer isso que vc quer, o problema é que vc não está sabendo usar o grid do Bootstrap. Inclusive esse pedaço de código nada tem a ver com o Bootstrap e o problema em si vc praticamente não falou

Comment: O problema surgiu fruto de um erro no projeto, assim a melhor resposta para esse problema foi refazer o projeto.

Answer (score 1):

Para isso pode usar [insertBefore()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore), [insertAdjacentElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement) ou [after()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/after)

Aqui um exemplo usando `after`, onde seleciono o elemento "pai" e adiciono o "fillho" após o mesmo. Lembrando que, o elemento é movido uma vez que já existe no DOM:

```js
document.getElementById("mover").addEventListener("click", function(){
   var filho = document.querySelector(".bloco-filho");
   var pai = document.querySelector(".bloco-pai");
   
   pai.after(filho);
});
```

```css
.bloco-pai {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: cyan
}

.bloco-filho {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: yellow
}
```

```html
<div class="bloco-pai">
    <div class="bloco-filho"></div>
</div>

<button id="mover">
Mover elemento
</button>
```