# Inserir Html dentro de Html sem alterar Estilos

Tags: html, css

Estou capturando emails para serem mostrados em tela, em html.

Porém minha página tem alguns estilos já aplicados, assim que incluo o html extraído do corpo do e-mail.

Os estilos presentes nesse html alteram o da minha página.

**Existe alguma forma de prevenir que os estilos "importados" alterem minha página ou "isolar" os estilos do html que vem do corpo do e-mail exclusivamente para uma div ?**

No exemplo abaixo, pode-se notar que o html vem com inúmeros estilos. E são exatamente esses que alteram todo o meu estilo original da página.

```
<style>
   *{ font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif; }
</style>

<div id="de" class="campo_email">
    <b>De</b>: teste@teste.com
</div>

<div id="para" class="campo_email">
    <b>Para</b>: teste@teste.com
</div>

<div id="data_envio" class="campo_email">
    <b>Data</b>: 2000-01-01 00:00:00
</div>

<div id="assunto" class="campo_email">
    <b>Assunto</b>: teste
</div>

<div id="assunto" class="campo_email">
    <b>Mensagem</b>: 
    <div id="mensagem">

       <!-- AQUI VAI O HTML DO CORPO DO EMAIL -->
       <!-- POR EXEMPLO O ABAIXO -->
       <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
       <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
          <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
          <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting">
         <title>Parab&eacute;ns! capSAT Rastreamento 24h</title>

        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,300i,400,400i,700,700i,800,800i" rel="stylesheet">

       </head>

       <body width="100%" style="margin: 0; padding: 0 !important; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; background-color: #222222; font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;">
            <center style="width: 100%; background-color: #f1f1f1;">


    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Por que não captura apenas os dados que precisa?

Comment: Por que não consigo prever respostas. Cada resposta terá um formato.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vc pode importar o email como um `iframe` no HTML, isso manteria o CSS do `iframe` insolado do seu. Ou então vc pode colocar `!important` em todos os estilos do seu HTML onde vai receber o conteúdo externo do email, tipo criando uma hierarquia de classe mais forte no seu documento sobrescrevendo o que vem externamente, isso pode funcionar caso o CSS que venha do email não esteja escrito *inline* diretamente na própria tag dos elementos...

Ou existe uma técnica ainda experimental, não funciona em todos os browser que é o `CSS Contain` (ela é tipo o antigo **[`Scoped CSS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style#Uma_folha_de_estilos_com_escopo)**)

> A propriedade `contain`  permite que um autor indique que elemento e seus conteúdos são, na medida do possível, independente do resto da árvore do documento. Isso permite que o navegador recalcule o layout, estilo, pintura, tamanho ou alguma combinação deles para uma área limitada do DOM e não da página inteira.

*Fonte:* https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/contain

Seu código ficaria assim:

```
.container {
    contain: strict; /* Indica que todas as regras de contenção são aplicadas ao elemento.  */
}

<div class="container">
    <!-- conteúdo vindo do email -->
</div>
```

Porém o suporte é muito limitado...

https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-containment

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Contain não tá funcionando nem a custo de reza.
O strict some com todo o conteudo da div, os outros não fazem diferença nenhuma.

Comment: Pode me detalhar como coloco o html no iframe ? Já que ele vem em texto direto do BD

Comment: @PedroAugusto que pena que não funcionou ai, mas como falei é algo ainda em Working Draft, não está totalmente implementado pelos navegadores. Cara tem que ver a forma como vc está injetando esse código na página. Teoricamente vc teria que pegar o que está no banco, criar um arquivo.HTML separado e criar um iframe no seu documento que vai carregar o .HTML que vc criou com o que estava no banco. Infelizmente não tenho conhecimento para te ajudar com essa rotina.

Comment: Da uma lida aqui tb, as vezes pode ajudar em algo https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/352318/para-que-serve-e-como-usar-o-display-contents-do-css

Comment: Iframe por enquanto foi a solução, continuo a pesquisa quem sabe rola algo melhor

Comment: @PedroAugusto pode ser que apareça outra solução, vamos ver se alguém posta algo, uma pena o `contain` não ter funcionado, eu mesmo nunca vi nenhuma aplicação usando ele rss. Sucesso ai []´s